# Is there any way to add rows with copy of data in two columns like this in Excel

Tags: excel

I can't find an answer. Maybe someone can help.
I have some huge tables with such data:

```
Column1  Column2
  first
 second   option
  third
 fourth   option
  fifth   option
```

I need to get another tables from it with one small change:

```
Column1  Column2
  first
 second
 second   option
  third
 fourth
 fourth   option
  fifth
  fifth   option
```

I want to automate the process with some Excel formulas that create result on one list from original. I tried to use INDEX formula, but didn't get right result. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one suggestion using a helper column which counts up by one only if the current row does not contain the word "option". Starting with a 1 in C2, then in C3:-

```
=IF(AND(INDEX(B$2:B$10,C2)="option",C1<>C2),C2,C2+1)
```

Then in D2:-

```
 =INDEX(A$2:A$10,C2)
```

and in E2:-

```
=IF(D2=D1,"option","")
```

[image]